# Change cfg and weight file in YOLO

Tags: python, yolo

I made a program with YOLO v2 and now I want to update it to YOLO v3.
For YOLO v2 and v3, the model is exactly same so I was just trying to change the cfg and weight file.

First I downloaded yolov3.cfg and weight file at [this link](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/).

And changed all `yolo.cfg` files to `yolov3.cfg` and got this error message:

```
C:\Program Files\CVD\lib\darkflow\darkflow\dark\darknet.py:54: UserWarning: darkflow/cfg/yolo.cfg not found, use darkflow/cfg/yolo.cfg instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doctorf\Miniconda3\envs\dark-flow\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-6.0b1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
  File "C:\Users\doctorf\Miniconda3\envs\dark-flow\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-6.0b1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
  File "CVD.py", line 154, in <module>
  File "CVD.py", line 67, in _main
  File "D:\Project\python\Tracking-with-darkflow\darkflow\darkflow\net\build.py", line 58, in __init__
  File "D:\Project\python\Tracking-with-darkflow\darkflow\darkflow\dark\darknet.py", line 17, in __init__
  File "D:\Project\python\Tracking-with-darkflow\darkflow\darkflow\dark\darknet.py", line 68, in parse_cfg
  File "D:\Project\python\Tracking-with-darkflow\darkflow\darkflow\utils\process.py", line 66, in cfg_yielder
  File "D:\Project\python\Tracking-with-darkflow\darkflow\darkflow\utils\process.py", line 17, in parser
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'darkflow/cfg/yolo.cfg'
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try rename your yolov3.cfg to yolo.cfg or replace the path of your file in darknet.py.